# Java 8 CompletableFuture vs Netty Future

Tags: java, java-8, netty, nonblocking, completable-future

How does the `CompletableFuture` introduced in JDK 8 compare with the `io.netty.util.concurrent.Future` provided by Netty ?

Netty documentation mentions that

> JDK 8 adds CompletableFuture which somewhat overlaps
>   `io.netty.util.concurrent.Future`
>   http://netty.io/wiki/using-as-a-generic-library.html

The questions I'm trying to get answers to are:

1. **What would their similarities and differences be?**
2. **How would the performance characteristics of the two differ? Which one would be able to scale better?**

With respect to the similarities/ differences, I have been able to come up with the following:

**Similarities:**
The fundamental similarity being that both are non-blocking as compared to the Java Future. Both the classes have methods available to add a listener to the future, introspect failure and success of the task and get results from the task.

**Differences:**
`CompletableFuture` seems to have a much richer interface for things like composing multiple async activities etc. Netty's `io.netty.util.concurrent.Future` on the other hand allows for multiple listeners to be added to the same Future, and moreover allows for listeners to be removed.

Comment: You can invoke `CompletableFuture.thenDoSomething()` methods multiple times, which is analogous to adding multiple listeners in other future frameworks.

Comment: Does CompletableFuture has an event loop like the Netty Future?

Comment: @user1870400 `CompletableFuture` (and any other class implementing `CompletionStage` ) have methods like `thenApply` and `thenApplyAsync` which work in different ways. Methods like `thenApply` will execute immediately on the same thread, while `thenApplyAsync` will execute using an `Executor`, which may be implemented with an event loop (although the default is a work stealing pool).

Comment: There is some discussion on the topic here: https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/2105

Answer (score 5):

If we look at that whole paragraph (especially the first sentence)

> Java sometimes advances by adopting ideas that subsume constructs
>   provided by Netty. For example, JDK 8 adds CompletableFuture which
>   somewhat overlaps io.netty.util.concurrent.Future. In such a case,
>   Netty's constructs provide a good migration path to you; We will
>   diligently update the API with future migration in mind.

What it's basically saying is that the netty `Future` and `CompletableFuture` are the same concept, but implemented at different times by different people.
Netty made their future because there wasn't one available in java, and they didn't want to pull one in as a dependency from something like Guice. But now, java has created one, and it's available for use.
In the end of the paragraph they're basically saying that the netty API may replace `Future` with `CompletableFuture` in the future.
As far as similarities/differences, they're both just one of many implementations of the [future/promise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises) pattern. Use the netty one when you're using the netty api and netty specific stuff, otherwise use `CompletableFuture`.